# DDD doesn't show the code anymore

Tags: c, ddd-debugger

I'm writing a C program. During "code & fix" phase I use DDD (gdb UI) to debug.

I compile with gcc -g and invoke ddd with

```
ddd ./a.out
```

DDD has worked well until, suddenly, when I invoke it, the code doesn't appear anymore.

All I visualize is the DDD default screen (the same screen that pops up when opening ddd with no parameters). I can start program from DDD as usual with Run command from Program menu.

I haven't modified any configuration files, and the change happened in the middle of the work, in absence of previous restarts. Then, I have tried to restart, and also to reinstall ddd, but with no success. 
Gdb works well.

I work on Linux Mint 17.3.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

I have uninstalled ddd with purge options:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ddd
```

Then remove ddd folder

```
rm -r ~/.ddd
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install ddd
```

Now it works!